# Can't merge table using cx_oracle in python

Tags: python, database, oracle, merge, cx-oracle

I'm trying to merge two tables by using cx_oracle.
The following sql language works at sql developer tools:

```
 MERGE INTO ASBODS_SDDM_SCHEMA.EULA_DATA E
    USING (SELECT * FROM ASBODS_SDDM_SCHEMA.EULA_STG_DATA) ES
    ON (E.MASTER_METER_NBR = ES.MASTER_METER_NBR AND E.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR AND 
    E.METER_NBR = ES.METER_NBR AND E.ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.ACCOUNT_NBR AND E.EULA_DATA_TYPE_CD = ES.EULA_STG_DATA_TYPE_CD)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    E.ACCEPTED_DT = ES.ACCEPTED_DT ,
    E.DECLN_OF_CONSENT_FLG = ES.DECLN_OF_CONSENT_FLG ,
    E.EULA_VERSION_NBR = ES.EULA_VERSION_NBR,
    E.SOFTWARE_VERSION_NBR = ES.SOFTWARE_VERSION_NBR,
    E.COMPANY_NM = ES.COMPANY_NM ,
    E.MACH_ID = ES.MACH_ID ,
    E.LOAD_DT = ES.LOAD_DT
    WHERE 
    E.MASTER_METER_NBR = ES.MASTER_METER_NBR AND E.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR AND 
    E.METER_NBR = ES.METER_NBR AND E.ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.ACCOUNT_NBR AND E.EULA_DATA_TYPE_CD = ES.EULA_STG_DATA_TYPE_CD
```

But when I insert this sql into cx_Orcale:

```
import cx_Oracle

try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/pwd@server')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(''' MERGE INTO ASBODS_SDDM_SCHEMA.EULA_DATA E
    USING (SELECT * FROM ASBODS_SDDM_SCHEMA.EULA_STG_DATA) ES
    ON (E.MASTER_METER_NBR = ES.MASTER_METER_NBR AND E.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR AND 
    E.METER_NBR = ES.METER_NBR AND E.ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.ACCOUNT_NBR AND E.EULA_DATA_TYPE_CD = ES.EULA_STG_DATA_TYPE_CD)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    E.ACCEPTED_DT = ES.ACCEPTED_DT ,
    E.DECLN_OF_CONSENT_FLG = ES.DECLN_OF_CONSENT_FLG ,
    E.EULA_VERSION_NBR = ES.EULA_VERSION_NBR,
    E.SOFTWARE_VERSION_NBR = ES.SOFTWARE_VERSION_NBR,
    E.COMPANY_NM = ES.COMPANY_NM ,
    E.MACH_ID = ES.MACH_ID ,
    E.LOAD_DT = ES.LOAD_DT
    WHERE 
    E.MASTER_METER_NBR = ES.MASTER_METER_NBR AND E.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.MASTER_ACCOUNT_NBR AND 
    E.METER_NBR = ES.METER_NBR AND E.ACCOUNT_NBR = ES.ACCOUNT_NBR AND E.EULA_DATA_TYPE_CD = ES.EULA_STG_DATA_TYPE_CD
     ''') 
    con.commit()
    
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print('There is problem with sql', e)

finally:
    if cursor:
        con.commit()
        cursor.close()
    if con:
        con.close()
```

It has long time no feedback in linux, seems it is running all the time,and not work.

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit in the tool session?  Maybe the tables are locked.

Answer (score 0):

instead of multi line merge statement  convert it to single line and try , I have already faced same issue . and it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).